# What is the most appropriate type of variable to use when coding a game's location? Boolean/String/Some other? (java)

Tags: java

First post so I hope this is an appropriate type question for this site. If not I'd appreciate it if someone could direct me to a more appropriate place. I'm extremely new at programming. I did a bit in high school and have recently decided to relearn starting with making a text-based survival game in Java7 using Eclipse.

Right now I'm coding the location superclass. The particular function I need help with is this: it needs to be able to keep track of which of 9 regions the user currently "is in" (which is then used in a large number of other classes for many various purposes. The location class also includes functionality for accepting user input to move to a new region, among various other things.) The way I started this was by making a boolean variable for each region and whenever a transition should occur that variable is set to true. But now I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way to do this. I have to take String inputs, run a method to standardize various acceptable answers into one, and then run it through a switch statement that makes the corresponding boolean variable true?

Would it be simpler to simply keep track of the location with a single String variable that gets set as whatever region the player is in? Or would that be more likely to cause errors or complications when coding? Would an array better suit this need? ***edit***: (I just want to thank you guys for people such an open and helpful community. Its really appreciated.)

**BIG EDIT:** I wanted to further elaborate on what the regions will eventually do. In each region there will eventually be a handful of places the user can go to that are generic with a small number of places unique to each location. Other major superclasses would be altered depending on what region the user is in (example: my "encounters" superclass would have variables that dictate how likely certain encounters are to happen (i.e. chance to a hostile attack) and these variables would be altered depending on the region) but also by other instances (The "Time" superclass would keep track of the day and time of day which would also effect the variables in "encounters".) The current plan was to make a class for each generic place (i.e. Walmart, technology store, grocery, public park, etc.) They would contain different properties depending on the region and would also effect classes like "encounters". I was going to have their properties defined by if/else & switch statements depending on what region the user was in. But now I'm realizing it would make more sense to define their properties when I create the object.

While a lot of people are steering me to enums, some are also suggesting I make classes for each region, (and I am also hearing about interfaces.) If I were to go with the 2nd route I have 3 questions: (a) If the region classes were all subclasses to "Location", then wouldn't I have a problem creating objects for all the generic places inside the region classes (i.e. Walmarts) because the Walmart class can only belong to one superclass? (If not what is the difference between an object being created in a class and the actual relationship between a superclass and its subclasses) (b) If I initialized each region as an object instead of simply recording it with a variable, how would I achieve the original task of remembering which region the user is in (for functions as simple as printing the region out to making alterations to variables in classes like "encounters"). Wouldn't I still need to have some sort of variable to identify the region? And if so, that what practical purpose does creating classes for the region accomplish? (I can see this might still let me make the code cleaner by housing the variables that interact with "encounters" instead of having to use if/else/switch statements inside the "encounters" class (also in this case *how* could I make the variables in the region classes interact with the variables in "encounters" since neither belong to each other) but anything else?) (c) Would it make more sense to create classes for every region or a single region class that gets defined differently when initialized and WHY?

Finally, I know I may have asked too many questions but could someone please explain to me the different utilities found in enums and interfaces (I'm especially interested in hearing about enums) and now that you know a little bit more, should I be using enums, interfaces, or some sort of classes for the regions? Thank you guys so much!

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code, but I think an [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) would be the best solution

Comment: I got a busy day of homework but I'll upload some code tonight (although a lot of the utilities of the program are in my head as I'm early in the project and am using it to learn things like this)

Comment: I think it's time to learn more about design patterns, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

If the list of 9 regions should not grow as game develops, you can describe each of them in hardcoded fashion also utilizing power of objects. Enums can have custom properties and methods weawing them into your architecture, and also enums provide some extra benefits such as `==` comparison and using in `switch` blocks.

---

**EDIT**

> I don't understand why this future addition might make enums a less desirable route

The only way to add an option to enum is to rewrite its class source code. That is, enum options are defined *statically* and in larger projects when developers should deal with product versions, compatibility, delivering to end-users etc., this could be a pain. In fact, any change in source code of published project is undesirable, since it requires recompilation and full rebuild of at least one (in best case) application module.

The way to deal with it is to move modifiable data into some **resource** (this can be a file, database table, plugin or anything easily modifiable without full rebuild) and make your application to initialize itself on startup *in runtime*. Since from this point your program no longer knows that data in advance, *statically*, there is no way you could define enum describing that data. And in this scenario [custom classes (Polygnome's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40444748/4412979) will do the job. Your program reads the resource, creates and initializes objects *in runtime* that describe your configuration and uses *dynamic* data.

IMHO, there is almost always tradeoff beween flexibility and complexity. You gain flexibility and freedom to modify region list, but you have to deal with complexity of dynamic solution. Or you decide to use much simpler enums understanding their limited extensibility.

Btw, in order of growing flexibility (and complexity):

raw primitives (int/String) | enums | custom classes

Comment: I'm going to take a look at enums. This suggestion seems like what I was hoping for by asking this question. And yes later in development I expect to add either 4 or 10 additional regions, but I don't understand why this future addition might make enums a less desirable route, as people here seem to allude to.

Answer (score 0):

Enum is very recommended, as stated by Vasily Liaskovsky.
Using int is a great way as well. For example:

```
int currentRegion;
static final int region1 = 0;
static final int region2 = 1;
static final int region3 = 2;
etc...
```

Make sure the region1 etc are stated final, so their IDs cannot be changed afterwards, static reference could save memory if you're using multiple location superclass objects, also easier accessible outside the class.
This way to check if you're in a certain region, just use a if statement:

```
if(currentRegion == region1) {}
```

To set it:

```
currentRegion = region1;
```

Simple as that

Comment: Enum gets mapped to an int anyways, though

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the usage of an enum here. An enum is great, but not extendable. What if you want to add another region?

So just create classes, and pass them around. They might hold some form of string as identifier (but you should load the proper name from a file that can be localized, anyways).

With a proper class, you can easily add new transitions betwen regions (make your region class a graph) and much more.

```
Region current = ...;
List<Transition> neighbours = current.getNeighbours();
foreach (Transition t : neighbours)
    System.out.println("To the " + transition.getDirection() + " is the " + transition.getTargetName()); 
    // prints e.g. "To the north is the shadowy jungle"
```

There are a lot of ways todo this, and in an OOP language, you should really try to get into the mindset of using objects instead of setting integer flags or else.

Comment: And the key question to prefer classes over enums is "Do I want to add more regions later?"

Comment: Noobie here and don't understand some of the terminology you used. What do you mean when you say an enum is not extendable? And could you please elaborate on 'making your region class a graph'? That sounds potentially useful.

Comment: @Connor Well, you can't add new values to an enum without breaking a whole lot of your codebase. Fall-throughs in switch-case statements are just one thing, and breaking bytecode compatibility with previos iterations is another. A graph an be modeled in various ways, one way would be to either teat your region as edge and store an vertex list (as shown above with the transition class) or by storing a list of neighbous directly. How you want to model it depends on what exactly you want to achieve, and what exactly you do with your regions.

Comment: If you frequently want to find out which regions are adjacent to the current region, it makes sense for your region class to provide that information in an easy way. If you have other requirements, then other things your region class should be able to do become important. Program design isn't done in a few sentences.